# Matplotlib works in my IDE, but not through cmd?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cmd, pycharm

I've installed `matplotlib` through `pip`, and it runs perfectly when I use it in `PyCharm`. However, when I run my Python file through cmd, I get the following error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I have installed other modules the same way, and those have no problems running in `PyCharm` or in cmd.

`Matplotlib` is installed under:

> C:\Users\David\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages

Something I noticed - perhaps the root of the problem - Is that `Python` seems to be installed in 2 places:

> C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe

The path above is also the path to my Python Interpreter on `PyCharm`.

and

> C: \Users\David\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

- Python version 3.8.5
- Windows 10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you also post the python interpreter path on pycharm

Comment: @deadshot I've edited the post to include this info

Comment: try installing it again through command prompt

Comment: @deadshot "pip install matplotlib" typed into the cmd went smoothly, but I got the same error message as before when running the file again through cmd

Answer (score 0):

try running the command `pip install matplotlib` in your cmd. It works for me.